# plotting two interp1d functions with secondary y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, spline

I have two interp1d functions using spline interpolation and I would like to add secondary axis on the plot.

```
f1 = interp1d(a, b, kind='cubic')
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

time = pd.to_datetime(a)
t = pd.to_datetime(x)

plt.plot(time,f1(time),color='green')
plt.plot(t,f2(t),color='red')
```

Output: [Interp1d plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWRIg.png)

Here are variable for x,y

```
x
array([1.5224544e+18, 1.5145920e+18, 1.5067296e+18, 1.4988672e+18,
   1.4910048e+18, 1.4831424e+18, 1.4746752e+18, 1.4668128e+18,
   1.4589504e+18, 1.4510880e+18, 1.4432256e+18, 1.4353632e+18,
   1.4275008e+18, 1.4196384e+18, 1.4117760e+18, 1.4039136e+18,
   1.3960512e+18, 1.3881888e+18, 1.3803264e+18, 1.3724640e+18,
   1.3646016e+18, 1.3567392e+18, 1.3488768e+18, 1.3410144e+18,
   1.3331520e+18, 1.3252896e+18, 1.3168224e+18, 1.3089600e+18,
   1.3010976e+18, 1.2932352e+18, 1.2853728e+18, 1.2775104e+18,
   1.2696480e+18, 1.2617856e+18, 1.2539232e+18, 1.2224736e+18,
   1.1910240e+18])

y
date
2018-03-31    0.208044
2017-12-30    0.202789
2017-09-30    0.201890
2017-07-01    0.200773
2017-04-01    0.200018
2016-12-31    0.201298
2016-09-24    0.207214
2016-06-25    0.212382
2016-03-26    0.218203
2015-12-26    0.223881
2015-09-26    0.224409
2015-06-27    0.222381
2015-03-28    0.221986
2014-12-27    0.219190
2014-09-27    0.212183
2014-06-28    0.213164
2014-03-29    0.210773
2013-12-28    0.208846
2013-09-28    0.211710
2013-06-29    0.218486
2013-03-30    0.230000
2012-12-29    0.249656
2012-09-29    0.264155
2012-06-30    0.266402
2012-03-31    0.268421
2011-12-31    0.255537
2011-09-24    0.236561
2011-06-25    0.232660
2011-03-26    0.221534
2010-12-25    0.215534
2010-09-25    0.213045
2010-06-26    0.211977
2010-03-27    0.208876
2009-12-26    0.197382
2009-09-26    0.186750
2008-09-27    0.151902
2007-09-29    0.125185
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Here are variable for a,b

```
a
array([1.5281568e+18, 1.4619744e+18, 1.4330304e+18, 1.3725504e+18,
       1.3489632e+18, 1.3093920e+18, 1.2988512e+18, 1.2832128e+18,
       1.2725856e+18, 1.2306816e+18, 1.2042432e+18, 1.1990592e+18,
       1.1726208e+18, 1.1648448e+18, 1.1516256e+18, 1.1386656e+18,
       1.1095488e+18, 1.0490688e+18])

b
2018-06-05    193.310000
2016-04-30     90.014780
2015-05-31    123.342948
2013-06-30     51.462246
2012-09-30     85.115356
2011-06-30     42.645786
2011-02-28     44.874186
2010-08-31     30.885067
2010-04-30     33.170639
2008-12-31     10.843441
2008-02-29     15.883386
2007-12-31     25.165422
2007-02-28     10.749426
2006-11-30     11.645106
2006-06-30      7.275968
2006-01-31      9.593301
2005-02-28      5.699318
2003-03-31      0.898221
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Also, I would be curious to know if there is a way to measure correlation between the two interp1d functions.

Could 
anyone 
suggest 
any 
guidance?

Thank 
you 
in 
advance.

---

So, I have tried to replicate your codes by resampling and interpolating using the following code.

```
f1_lin = interp1d(a, b, kind='linear')
f1_cub = interp1d(a, b, kind='cubic')
f1_near = interp1d(a, b, kind='nearest')

t=np.linspace(min(a),max(a))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b, 'o', label = 'original data')
plt.plot(t,f1_lin(t), '.',label = 'resampled via linear interpolation')
plt.plot(t, f1_cub(t), '1', label='resampled via cubic spline interpolation')
plt.plot(t, f1_near(t), '_', label='resampled via nearest value interpolation')

plt.legend()
```

Which gives me the same results you have provided. If I do the same for

```
f1_lin1 = interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')

t1=np.linspace(min(x),max(x))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', label = 'original data')
plt.plot(t1,f1_lin1(t1), '.',label = 'resampled via linear interpolation')

plt.legend()
```

I get the following output: [f1_lin1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjUYh.png)

But how would I be able to use these functions to further drive the statistical evaluation given values of f1_lin(t) and f1_lin1(t1) do not correspond to the matching time frame.

Comment: a secondary y-axis is created by `plt.twinx()`, placed right before the second `plot`call. But what do you mean by correlation? To calculate the correlation in a mathematical sense, you could use `np.correlate`, but for this the signals should be resampled, I think.

Comment: ... and why do you use an interpolation function? you just do not interpolate?

Comment: Thanks for the plt.twinx() suggestion. This works like a charm. For the correlation part, I want to evaluate statistical evaluation/relationship between x and b. Since x and b have different time series date to compare, I used interpolation. Can you suggest better way to perform this ?(np.correlate(y,b) or np.correlate(f1, f2) do not seem to work.

Comment: No, interpolating, resampling - sth like that is necessary, that's for sure. But you do not do Interpolation in your code: the interpolated time values are the _same_ as the original ones, so there is no interpolation done. Just compare `plt.plot(time,f1(time),color='green')
`with `plt.plot(a, b),color='green')` - it's identical. I'll give you further hints as soon as possible. But until then: check `interp1` in more detail and perhaps pandas `resample` (might be easier).

Comment: I understand plt.plot(time,f1(time),color = 'green') and plt.plot(a,b,color = 'green') produces the same outcome. I used interpolation so that I can connect the dots on the missing data. So that for a given date, I would have an approximate idea where y values would be. Are you suggesting resampling is a better way to go?

Comment: You _can_, exactly, but you do not in your code, because you feed the same time values into the interpolating function that you already have.

Comment: What do you mean by feeding same time values into the interpolating function. Also, can you provide some guidance?
How do you align the values of y and b when I don't have the corresponding time series aligned to make comparison?

Comment: By 'feeding' I mean, that you calculated an interpolation function, but you did not use it for _re_sampling, because you calculated values at the time values you already had before. The resulting array of data is the same array like your original data. Perhaps my answer edit Shows even better what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Before you want to calculate correlation, you might want to have closer look to what interpolation and resampling means.

If you want to resample your data, you'll obviously have to *create new* data points inbetween your original samples. Now, this should be done carefully, with respect to the characteristic of the data source, otherwise you'll introduce too big errors and your results do not show properties of your data, but only properties of the model you used to find the interpolated samples for your data.

In short: resampling needs interpolation first, and interpolation can be done in many different ways, e.g. linear, cubic spline or nearest value interpolation, just to name a few.

However, which *model* fits most perfect to your data is up to you to decide, as varying the type will have a massive impact where the resampled data values are found - have a look at this:

[image]

created with:

```
t = np.linspace(min(a), max(a))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, b, 'o', label='original data')
plt.plot(t, f1_lin(t), '.', label='resampled via linear interpolation')
plt.plot(t, f1_cub(t), '1', label='resampled via cubic spline interpolation')
plt.plot(t, f1_near(t), '_', label='resampled via nearest value interpolation')
plt.legend()
```

Linear interpolation is self explaining I think. The cubic spline interpolation calculates cubic splines between every subsequent pair of datapoints with a smooth transition from one to the next. Nearest value, well, just copies the nearest original data sample.
But the point here is: the differences are so big, that you can imagine, that the choice of the interpolation function will severely affect the result of your correlation in the next step.